# Install the Angular CLI [Problem : Error message]

Tags: angular, macos-high-sierra

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Arnold:first_app arnoldk.$ npm install -g @angular/cli
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/arnoldk./.npm/_logs/2021-01-27T09_41_01_867Z-debug.log
```

I have this error message when I type this syntax on the terminal:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

What happens with this installation?
I use a MacBook Pro mid-2010
macOs High Sierra 10.13.6

Comment: try sudo npm install -g @angular/cli

Comment: I try it, I have the same message. In the message, the terminal talks about some permissions, that I have to change on the folder...

Comment: `
MacBook-Pro-de-Arnold:Angular_Projects arnoldk.$ sudo npm install -g @angular/cli@lastest
Password:
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for @angular/cli@lastest.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/arnoldk./.npm/_logs/2021-01-27T10_00_29_072Z-debug.log
`

Comment: Did you navigate to any folder before you tried to install the Angular CLI?

Comment: No, but my browser is open and I am worked on a WordPress Website.

MacBook-Pro-de-Arnold:Angular_Projects arnoldk.$ sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
Password:
npm ERR! code FETCH_ERROR
npm ERR! errno FETCH_ERROR
npm ERR! Response timeout while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular-devkit%2fschematics (over 300000ms)

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/arnoldk./.npm/_logs/2021-01-27T10_26_03_196Z-debug.log

Comment: `MacBook-Pro-de-Arnold:Angular_Projects arnoldk.$ sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
Password:
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142

changed 240 packages, and audited 241 packages in 31s

20 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities`